# Domain in Node.js - Does it keep and modify the parent context?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When modifying a variable inside a [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_class_domain) are they modified in the parent context ?

Comment: Variables are not connected to domains.

Comment: I have a global variable in my main app, if I modify it inside a domain, is the global variable also modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domains just track asynchronous context; they do not affect variables at all.

Comment: Ok so it acts like a common function. It's a great mechanism!

Comment: So let's say there is something bad happening in my code, domain doesnt protect from this right? If an error appears in a domain and that I catch it I should exit the current process?